# How to dynamically create a list of Javascript objects into comma separated objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create a comma separated list of objects within another object in Javascript? At least that's what I think I'm trying to do.

The end result I'm looking for is this:

```
var endresult = { 'MD': { fill: 'yellow' }, 'VA': { fill: 'blue' }, 'IL': { fill: 'red' }, 'SC': { fill: 'green' } };
```

I've tried using Arrays, creating classes, Array.join(), creating multiple strings and concatenating. I've also tried creating key object value pairs, but I can't seem to successfully create one.

The general objective is to take a list of State and Color variables, pass them into a class of key : object value pairs, then add this new instantiated object to a list that will then be passed into the variable endresult with the same syntax as the example code provided.

Thanks in advance (I have a feeling I'm about to be schooled).

Comment: Please post an example of the data you are wanting to transform

Comment: How does this have anything to do with jQuery? Please edit question, provide all the needed information and make sure that we are on the same page so you get an appropriate answer.

Comment: @RobertRocha I was thinking jQuery could be used to help solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two arrays, one with states, another with color names, you could use this function to get the end result:

```js
function combine(states, colors) {
    return colors.reduce( (result, color, i) => 
        Object.assign(result, { [states[i]]: { fill: color } }), {});
    
}

// sample data
var states = ['MD', 'VA', 'IL', 'SC'];
var colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'green'];

// convert
var result = combine(states, colors);

// output
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This answers got me in the right direction. Thanks!                                                  var StateStyles = {};

$.each(data, function (i, item) { 
     StateStyles[item.state] = { fill: item.color };
);

Comment: You're welcome. If I would have known the structure of `data`, I would have customised the solution to that. But good to see you got it ;-)

Comment: And I think that's where I was having a problem describing the problem. I didn't know that the structure of an object could have keys defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = {LA: {fill: 'blue'}};
colors['MA'] = {fill: 'red'};
//colors is now === {LA: {fill: 'blue'}, MA: {fill: 'red'}};
```

Keep in mind, when you use the Object[key] notation, the key ultimately needs to be a string for it to work as you intend.

Though, if 'fill' is the only value you intend to keep, you could simplify your object by just eliminating the `{fill: 'color'}` object and do `{LA: 'blue', ...}`.

See:

[Mozilla Property accessors docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Answer (score 0):

```
var StateStyles = {};

$.each(data, function (i, item) { 
     StateStyles[item.state] = { fill: item.color };
);
```

I appreciate the help everyone.I learned from trincot and Andrew Babin what was missing; I had to assign a key using the brackets. Now I have an object with multiple objects within it. Didn't know that could be done.